# Why my Ubuntu 13.04 is booting so slow and fails many time?

Tags: 13.04, boot

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and linux. I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Inspiron 15R Special Edition, it runs fine.Except that it boots very slow. Sometimes gets stuck at the Ubuntu logo with dots. Sometimes it gets me to login but touch pad doesn't work.

Please guide me.

System config:

- EFI based boot.
- Intel Core i5 3210M
- 1TB HDD
- AMD Radeon 7750M

Here's my boot chart: http://s24.postimg.org/5ocbq7wh1/prateekpc_raring_20130916_12.png

Comment: This could be a driver issue. Install the proper drivers using the answer in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to **Ubuntu**, but in general, for *most Linux systems*,

```
gedit /var/log/dmesg
```

or use a file manager like nautilus to navigate to that folder for this plain ordinary text file. Use the editor's Search/Find feature for words like **"fail"** or **"error"** if the logfile is really long. This is a good place to begin, if you are looking for problems during bootup. There are other logs in that directory you can check as well, but IMHO & experience, dmesg has been more often than not the best indicator to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just realized you have an **ATI Radeon 5500** series. I have a Radeon 7750 which gave me problems at first and had to install proprietary *fglrx* drivers before it worked properly.

Comment: I too have the same graphics adapter, but I turn it off each boot via switcheroo. Can that be the reason of lagged boot?

Comment: Oh right. Strange. I thought your message posted with a 5500. Need coffee. Yes, I had this problem with other Linux installs as well. My Debian install wouldn't even boot up until I gave it the display drivers it wanted. I think you can get the fglrx drivers from the *"non-free"* package. There's plenty of info on the web with other people who ran into this problem. By law, Linux distros can't package these into their installs for patent/copyright issues with the firmware, but they are easy enough to find and download.

Comment: OK, just looked it up. If you are able to get Ubuntu running, go to **System Settings** and click on **Software & Updates**. Last panel is **Additional Driver**. I switched to **fglrx-updates**. Reboot after that. See if that helps.